# Save an MS Word 2010 document where others cannot modify it

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word-2010, read-only

I am using Microsoft Word 2010 and I have created a document that individuals will fill out on a daily basis. When they are done I would like it to automatically be saved as a "Read Only" document in which I have a password for editing. Can this be done

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  There definitely seems to be more here than is being explained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct option in MS WORD 2010 to save a document as Read Only.
What you can do is -
Save the file --> Right Click on it and go to properties --> Change its attributes to Read-Only.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You should think more about the workflow. Where do they get the doc from? When are they done? What if thy we're to save partway through?

You could create a windows folder they can only write to, not modify, which might do what you want. But you might be better off using some form-filling software/system like google docs forms or woofoo or similar, so you can also process their input more easily.